# Jenkins job disk usage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I recently installed Jenkins disk usage plugin in my office CI environment. I was amazed to see that some of the jobs were occupying as high as 15GB of hard disk space ( this does not include builds and workspace). I have been looking all over the internet to find out what the job disk usage field actually signify. 
Can somebody please help me in understanding it ??

Answer (score 1):

Then [JENKINS Disk Usage Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Disk+Usage+Plugin) (presented [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/disk-usage)) has a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/disk-usage-plugin), and [issues about size](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22335?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20component%20%3D%20disk-usage-plugin%20AND%20text%20~%20%22size%22).

Notably [JENKINS-22335](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22335) "The disk usage size displayed for each build in the Build History is sometimes incorrect".

That issue includes:

> disk-usage calculates build disk usage by two ways
>
> - after build (to have info about build size as soon as possible) and
> - in recalculation thread (which is executed by global configuration setting - as user wants it to be executed).
>
> So if you change build size after its build (delete something), disk-usage does not reflect this change until recalculation thread is executed.
>   It is logical, in opposite approach disk-usage has to scan all builds for changes and recalculates them all the time - this would be a really performance issue, because calculation of disk usage is very expensive in large instances.
>   Even current behaviour can cause performance issues in large instances.

So it seems to only take into account build and workspace.
Double-check on the slave itself if there are any other big files to justify such a gap between "workspace+build" and the "job disk space" reported by the plugin.